# Symbol not found: _kAXXCAttributeAbsoluteValue Xcode Beta5 XCTest on iOS 8

Tags: xctest, xcode7-beta5

Running tests on iOS 8 from Xcode Beta 5 is crashing with this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _kAXXCAttributeAbsoluteValue
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXRuntime.framework/AXRuntime
 in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
```

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I have the same problem, but it is just a regression in the beta. For now I am using iOS 9 simulator to run my tests.

Comment: @TomaszBąk do you know if it has been reported?

Comment: I reported it to Apple.

Comment: Thread to follow on [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/39140)

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.

Comment: Same problem here !!, Any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed in Xcode 7 beta 6.